# How to write the case function with join two table

Tags: oracle

I have a sale table and a customer table. I need to get a total sale count in particular months and join that sale table with the customer table with customer key. And get the customer count wise customer status and month.

```
sale_table
cus_key   sale_date
43234     12/5/2020
42312     13/5/2020
52345     20/5/2020
4523      04/5/2020
45351     12/5/2020
7886      25/5/2020
2134      12/5/2020
64204     10/5/2020
```

```
cus_table
cus_key   status    date
43234       PD      20/5/2020
42312       PD      30/5/2020
45351       PD      02/6/2020
52345       PD      05/7/2020
```

```
output table
Total_sale   Count_PD_on_May  Count_PD_on_Jun   Count_PD_on_July
8                  2                1                 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT S.ROWID) AS TOTAL_SALE.
       COUNT(CASE WHEN C.STATUS = 'PD' AND C.SALE_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-05-01' AND DATE '2020-05-31' 
                  THEN 1 
             END) AS COUNT_PD_ON_MAY,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN C.STATUS = 'PD' AND C.SALE_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-06-01' AND DATE '2020-06-30' 
                  THEN 1 
             END) AS COUNT_PD_ON_JUN,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN C.STATUS = 'PD' AND C.SALE_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-07-01' AND DATE '2020-07-31' 
                  THEN 1 
             END) AS COUNT_PD_ON_JUL
  FROM SALE_TABLE S
  LEFT JOIN CUST_TABLE C ON C.CUST_KET = S.CUST_KEY
        AND C.SALE_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-05-01' AND DATE '2020-07-31'
 WHERE S.SALE_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-05-01' AND DATE '2020-05-31'
```

Comment: i tried this code, month-wise counts are correct but total sale count is incorrect

Comment: For sample data, what you find in total sale count?

Comment: Sale table have all such as PD status, C status. but I need to get total sale count (include PD, C status) and monthly breakdown count want only PD status count